# PHP 8 error Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: strftime()

Tags: wordpress, datetime, strftime, php-8

The code below works fine with PHP 7.4 but in PHP 8 it gives error.

```
// Add a Header
function filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns( $columns ) {
    // Add new column
    $columns['pickup_date'] = 'Afhaaldatum';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns', 10, 1 );

// Populate the Column
function action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'pickup_date' ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );      
        // Loop though order shipping methods
        foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $shipping_item ) {
            // Get appoitment start
            $pickup_appointment_start = $shipping_item->get_meta( '_pickup_appointment_start' );
        
           date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');       
        
            /* Set locale to Dutch */
            setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
            $startdate = strftime('%e %B %Y om %H:%M uur', $pickup_appointment_start );
    
            if(!empty($startdate))
         //         echo '<p>' .$startdate. '  <br> om  ' . $endtime . '  uur</p>';
              echo '<p>' .$startdate. '</p>';

            // Testing (to be removed) - Empty value case
            else
                echo '<small>-</small>';

            break;        
        }       
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: strftime(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given in /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/class.execute.snippet.php(635) : eval()'d code:29 
Stack trace:
#0 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/class.execute.snippet.php(635) : eval()'d code(29): strftime('%e %B %Y om %H:...', '') 
#1 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column('pickup_date', 49721) 
#2 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) 
#3 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#4 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php(1363): do_action('manage_shop_ord...', 'pickup_date', 49721) 
#5 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1532): WP_Posts_List_Table->column_default(Object(WP_Post), 'pickup_date') 
#6 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php(1397): WP_List_Table->single_row_columns(Object(WP_Post)) 
#7 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php(807): WP_Posts_List_Table->single_row(Object(WP_Post), 0) 
#8 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php(783): WP_Posts_List_Table->_display_rows(Array, 0) 
#9 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1444): WP_Posts_List_Table->display_rows() 
#10 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1371): WP_List_Table->display_rows_or_placeholder() 
#11 /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-admin/edit.php(487): WP_List_Table->display() 
#12 {main} thrown in /home/website/domains/WEBSITEX/public_html/debug/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/class.execute.snippet.php(635) : eval()'d code on line 29

i changed the format from datetime but that is also not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A careful reading of the first line of your error message reveals the problem.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: strftime(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given

The only line in your snippet using that function is

```
$startdate = strftime('%e %B %Y om %H:%M uur', $pickup_appointment_start );
```

You get that `$pickup_appointment_start` from WooCommerce's `->get_meta()` function, here.

```
$pickup_appointment_start = $shipping_item->get_meta( '_pickup_appointment_start' );
```

As your error message makes clear, you got back a text string for your metadata. A timestamp is an integer like `1667571169`. Is it possible your metadata for that particular item is rubbish?  Whatever it is, you can force it to be an integer with [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php). But it might come out zero.

The php [manual page for strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) makes clear that the function is deprecated.

You should replace it with a call to [wp_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/). That function returns `false` if the timestamp is rubbish. Use it with your site settings to find your localized formatting.

```
$startdate = wp_date(
     get_option( 'date_format' ) . ' ' . get_option( 'time_format' ),
     $pickup_appointment_start,
     get_option( 'timezone_string' );

if ( ! $startdate )  ... echo etc.
```